# VBA use range with variable

Tags: vba, excel

I want to copy a range of table and paste it in a new workbook. Columns A is always copied. In addition to it, I want to copy other ranges composed of other columns but as variable. For example, added to columns A, I copy columns C and E. I tried several methods but I didn't get it! This is what I wrote:

```
Sub Macro3()
Dim col1 As String
Dim copyrange1 As String
Dim copyrange2 As String
col1 = InputBox("first columns:")
copyrange1 = col1 & ":" & col1
col2 = InputBox("second columns:")
copyrange2 = col2 & ":" & col2
Range("A:A,copyrange1,copyrange2").Select
'Range("H2").Activate
Selection.Copy
Workbooks.Add
ActiveSheet.Paste
'Range("E5").Select
Windows("Pedro.xlsm").Activate
End Sub
```

kann you help me please solve it? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Are you entering the columns as a letter or a number?

Comment: It's as letter. col1 and col2 as String. at the end i get for exampel copyrange1 = C:C

Comment: You need to remove the copyrange1 and copyrange2 from inside your quotes in the Select line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work for you, note that it only copies the columns you enter...ex - Entering C and E only copies A,C,E.  It does not copy C, D, and E if you enter C and E.

```
Sub Macro3()
Dim col1 As String, col2 as String
Dim copyrange1 As Range, copyrange2 As Range, CopyRange3 As Range
col1 = InputBox("first columns:")
col1 = col1 & ":" & col1
Set copyrange1 = Range(col1)
col2 = InputBox("second columns:")
col2 = col2 & ":" & col2
Set copyrange2 = Range(col2)
Set CopyRange3 = Union([A:A], copyrange1, copyrange2)
CopyRange3.Copy
'Range("H2").Activate
'Selection.Copy
Workbooks.Add
ActiveSheet.Paste
'Range("E5").Select
Windows("Pedro.xlsm").Activate
End Sub
```